# extract string from object array

Tags: php, foreach, campaign-monitor

I have the following php:

```
$getlists = new CS_REST_Campaigns($_POST['campaign_id'], $auth);
$getlistsresult = $wrap->get_lists_and_segments();

if($getlistsresult->was_successful()) {

   echo '<pre>';
    var_dump($getlistsresult->response);
    echo '</pre>';
}
```

The above outputs:

```
 object(stdClass)#310 (2) {
  ["Lists"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    object(stdClass)#309 (2) {
      ["ListID"]=>
      string(32) "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
      ["Name"]=>
      string(6) "List 1"
    }
  }
  ["Segments"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
}
```

How would i target / extract the ListID?

I have tried the following which doesnt return anything:

```
foreach($getlistsresult->response->Results as $entry) {
    echo $entry->ListID;
}
```

Comment: You are missing the $value, you only have a key in your foreach now. Foreach ($row as $key => $value)

Comment: @Marijke Foreach loops in php default to using the $value after the as, it only gives you the key if you ask for it ($key => $value)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like there's a mistake in your foreach:

```
foreach($getlistsresult->response->Lists as $entry) {
    echo $entry->ListID;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are writing `Lists` as `Results`.

```
foreach($getlistsresult->response->Lists as $entry) {
   echo $entry->ListID;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

directly by:

```
echo $getlistsresult->response->Lists[0]->ListID
```

or all:

```
foreach($getlistsresult->response->Lists as $entry) {
   echo $entry->ListID;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try type casting

```
$array   = (array)$getlistsresult->response
$array   = $array["Lists"]

 foreach($array as $value)
 {
    echo $value['ListID']
 }
```

or use [**object Iteration**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.iterations.php)

```
$list   = $getlistsresult->response->Lists
foreach($list as $key=>$value)
{
    echo $value->ListId
 }
```